# How to calculate the character of this series $\displaystyle{\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^n\left(\frac{\ln n-1}{n^3+1}\right)}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I calculate the character of this series? Can you could show me the steps to follow? Thank you
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^n\left(\frac{\ln n-1}{n^3+1}\right)$$

Comment: We don't really want to start at $n=0$ since $\ln 0$ is not defined. Look at the absolute values of the terms. (For $n\gt 2$ this is just obtained by erasing the $(-1)^n$.) Use limit comparison with $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ to conclude absolute convergence.

Comment: So i can start from $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }$ if i delete the $(-1)^n$ ?

Comment: It does not matter where you start as far as convergence is concerned. I would start at $n=3$, because then $\ln n-1$ is positive.

Comment: I have a doubt: argument $An$ of the alternating series is always positive? so i don't need to check if they are? or i always have to change the starting value if is negative?

Comment: Or take the absolute values and then you can start at $n=1$. But (as in the Limit Comparison Test) we are only interested in large $n$. Note that our series, after the first couple of terms, is an alternating series. The alternating series test will then tell you that the given series converges. But we can assert more than mere convergence because of "cancellations." We actually have absolute convergence.

Answer (score 1):

For $n>0$ we have 
$$\left|(-1)^n\left(\frac{\ln n-1}{n^3+1}\right)\right|\le\frac{n-1}{n^3+1}<\frac{n}{n^3}=\frac{1}{n^2}$$
It follows that the series is absolutly convergent since from comparison test, since $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Alternating Series test.

Comment: I have a doubt: argument An of the alternating series is always positive? so i don't need to check if they are?